# async problem with node-downloader-helper

Tags: node.js

i am trying this npm and it worked, but i need to do some stuff that i cant handle how to...
I have an array of url that will download a pdf, i want to make a function that RETURNS an array of the finalPath of every one of them.
The problem is that i dont know how to manipulate a variable that is getting that info,
This is my code

```
let source_files = [
    'http://g500603svglh.cencosud.corp:8080/Facturacion/PDFServlet?docId=uR1v4VhQHvkjnXftjwSnTA==',
    'http://g500603svglh.cencosud.corp:8080/Facturacion/PDFServlet?docId=uR1v4VhQHvna6Kn8/UxIUQ=='
]
// ^Array with urls
async function transformPdf(arrPdfs) {
    console.log(arrPdfs.length);
    const pathSave = '/home/humberto/Escritorio/test' //path where will download all the pdf's
    return arrPdfs.map(url => { // mapping of the array
        const download = new DownloaderHelper(url, pathSave) //instanciate the downloadHelper with an url and the downloadPath
        let path;
        download.on('end', async() => {//i think this is things to do MEANWHILE it downloads (not sure)
            path = await download.getDownloadPath() //getting the path
            console.log("Inside:", path)//at this point i DO have the path i need
        })
        download.start(); //Start the download...i think
        console.log("Final", path);//Checking if have info yet (gives undefined)
        return path //trying to return the path to the array that will return
    })
}

let res = transformPdf(source_files)
console.log(">>", res);
```

I dont know how to manipulate that one line that i need that is

```
path = await download.getDownloadPath()
```

Thank you very much

npm link

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-downloader-helper
```

---

Trying with promise All

```
const download2 = async urlArray => {
    const pathSave = '/home/humberto/Escritorio/test'
    const downloadedPath = [];
    let pa = await Promise.all(urlArray.map(async url => {
        const dl = new DownloaderHelper(url, pathSave);
        dl.on('end', () => {
            downloadedPath.push(dl.getDownloadPath());
        });
        await dl.start();
    }))
    console.log(pa);
};

download2(urlSources);
```

Comment: make promises for all urls which resolve to what you want (path), then await them all see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: edited, that way you say?